# How to make an image cover as much space as possible in screen without loosing proportions in Java?

Tags: java, image, canvas

I have an image that I want to make as big as possible without losing proportions. I also want it to work in different screen sizes. I am using the following code which doesn't preserve proportions:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double screen_width = screenSize.getWidth();
double screen_height = screenSize.getHeight();

Image img = ImageIO.read(<PATH_TO_IMAGE>);
img = img.getScaledInstance((int)screen_width, (int)screen_height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Is there a way to resize an image while preserving proportions and still take as much space as possible on the screen.

Comment: You cant cover the whole screen and still keep the proportions - I think that's your imagining - if you want the proportions then the cover could be really bad -  if you want to cover the whole screen you have to go bigger than the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices here: keep the whole image in view but possibly leaving a lot of space uncovered, or cover the whole screen but possibly putting some of the image outsize thus not visible.

In both cases to keep the proportions you need to scale with a single factor.

case a)

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(....));
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double screen_width = screenSize.getWidth();
double screen_height = screenSize.getHeight();
double scalex=screen_width/img.getWidth(), scaley=screen_height/img.getHeight();
double scale=Math.min(scalex, scaley);
int w=(int)(scale*img.getWidth()), h=(int)(scale*img.getHeight());
BufferedImage img2=new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
img2.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
```

case b)

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(....));
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double screen_width = screenSize.getWidth();
double screen_height = screenSize.getHeight();
double scalex=screen_width/img.getWidth(), scaley=screen_height/img.getHeight();
double scale=Math.max(scalex, scaley);
int w=(int)(scale*img.getWidth()), h=(int)(scale*img.getHeight());
BufferedImage img2=new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
img2.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Swing, you can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). With the `StretchIcon` you can configure it to:

1. fill the entire space available, or
2. keep the image proportions and scale as much as possible.

So you would :

1. create the `StretchIcon` with your image
2. add the `Icon` to a `JLabel`
3. add the label to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of your `JFrame`

Now as the frame is resize the Icon is automatically resized.